# Is it okay to exclude unneeded migrations when committing code in a Laravel project?

Tags: git, laravel, database-migration

A simple example:

1. I make a migration that creates a `posts` table. It has a body field, that is of the type `string()`. After running the migration, data is added to the table.
2. I change my mind and add another migration to change the `string()` type to a `text()` type. I run this migration.
3. I change my mind again and add yet another migration to reverse the previous one -- change `text()` back to `string()`. I run this migration, too.
4. I add another column to the same table, called `view_count`.

As you can see, step 3 reverses the action performed by step 2, so it would be redundant to commit this code and have the deployment process follow the sequence. What I'd like to do is simply commit step 1 and step 4, which, I expect, should not affect the code or the behaviour in any way. The migrations have been run locally, so I can just leave the files there for now. (I could even delete the two files and run `composer dump-autoload`, right?), When the code is merged and deployed on another server, it simply won't run those two steps.

Is this expectation correct? Are there any other problems I'm likely to face?

I'm doing this using Laravel 5.4, but I believe the version irrelevant.

Comment: You should generally commit all your work in Git.  If, locally, you make a change and then undo it, and you haven't committed yet, then it would not become a part of your history by definition.

Comment: Thats sounds perfectly fine, you should be good to go after commiting migration 1 + 4, or preferably merge them into one single migration if you are still in development

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I would suggest that you merge the migrations into a single migration so it is a little cleaner but I wouldn't see any problems with this.

Personally, I prefer to keep all of my migrations, even the undeeded ones just so that I can keep a record of everything I have done, but if you feel it would be better for you to exclude them, that is perfectly fine.

If your application is in production, it could be a little tricky, and in that case, I would highly suggest that you keep the migration's separate.